# Removing permutations from a list

Tags: python-3.x, combinations

I am trying to remove duplicates from a list of permutations to just leave the combinations , the list of number is as follows:

```
[[1, 3, 11, 13], [1, 7, 11, 9], [1, 9, 11, 7], [1, 15, 9, 3], [3, 1, 11, 13], [3, 5, 11, 9], [3, 15, 9, 1], [5, 3, 11, 9], [5, 11, 9, 3], [5, 13, 9, 1], [7, 1, 11, 9], [7, 11, 9, 1], [9, 1, 11, 7], [11, 5, 9, 3], [11, 7, 9, 1], [13, 5, 9, 1], [15, 1, 9, 3], [15, 3, 9, 1]]
```

Here is a method I have made but none of the list being printed is empty :

```
def permtocomb(fcombs):
     fcombinations=fcombs 
     global value
     global comp
     global count
     global combs
     global b
     for z in range(0,len(fcombinations)):
         count = 0
         print('testing array'+str(fcombinations[z]))
         for x in range(0,4):
             value=fcombinations[z][x]
             for j in range(0,len(fcombinations)):

                 print('against arrqay'+str(fcombinations[j]))
                 for v in range(0,4):
                     if value==fcombinations[j][v]:
                         count+=1
                         b=j
         if count<=3:
             #fcombinations.pop(fcombinations[c])
             combs.append(fcombinations[b])


    permtocomb(fcombinations)
    print(fcombinations)
    print(combs)
```

Are there any python plugins or builtins capable of removing permutations just leaving the combinations?

Comment: Probably you could use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) to do that.

Comment: What is your expected output, can you show an example of what you consider duplicate?

Comment: E.g (1,3,11,13) and (3,1,11,13) is a duplicate in my case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usually a bad idea to use global variables as it makes debugging very hard.
Here's a very simple way to do this, just keep a record of what you have `seen`. You can use `set` to ignore combinations but `set`s are unhashable so you can use `frozenset`s, e.g.:

```
In []:
data = [[1, 3, 11, 13], ...]
seen = set()
result = []
for d in data:
    if frozenset(d) not in seen:
        result.append(d)
        seen.add(frozenset(d))
result

Out[]:
[[1, 3, 11, 13], [1, 7, 11, 9], [1, 15, 9, 3], [3, 5, 11, 9], [5, 13, 9, 1]]
```

If you don't care about order this can be simplified:

```
In []:
[list(e) for e in set(frozenset(d) for d in data)]

Out[]:
[[1, 11, 9, 7], [11, 1, 3, 13], [9, 13, 5, 1], [1, 3, 9, 15], [11, 9, 3, 5]]
```

However, if you really don't care about order you may want to just leave it as a `set` of `frozenset`s:

```
set(frozenset(d) for d in data)
```

Note: This assumes there are no duplicate values in each of your elements (which your example data doesn't have), if you do have multiple values you will need to switch to multisets (`collections.Counter()`).